# How should these types of integrals be solved? $\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\ln y}$

Tags: integration, substitution

$$\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\ln y}dy$$

$$\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{\ln^2y}dy$$

I know that i should use some substitution, but i don't understand how.Is there any other way than substitution?

I've tried to understand the integral-calculator.com output, but no luck.

Can anyone explain to me how to solve these integrals?

Comment: What is the exact source of this problem, and what specific math education have you had in the field of calculus integration?  Please respond by editing your posting; please do not respond with a comment.

Comment: use $u = ln(y) \Rightarrow du = \frac{1}{y} dy$

Comment: I'm learning integration currently in my calculus class. Shouldn't dy be there at the end in the question for solving ? Or is it not compulsory ?

Comment: @Gwen Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Using substitution with $u = \ln(y)$ should do the trick. With the chosen $u$ we have that $du = \frac{1}{y}dy$, then we can rewrite the integral as:

$$
\int \frac{dy}{y\ln(y)} = \int \frac{du}{u}
$$

Which is easy to integrate. With the other integral, we can use the same substitution

$$
\int \frac{dy}{y\ln^2(y)} = \int \frac{du}{u^2}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't $du=\frac{1}{y} dy $

Comment: yes small error @Gwen

Comment: @A.Person Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We have that $(\ln(y))'=\dfrac{1}{y}$.

It is well known that for every differentiable function $f$ and $n\neq -1$, $$\displaystyle\int f'(x)f(x)^n=\dfrac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

Therefore, if $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\neq 1$, we will have $$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{y\ln(y)^k}=\dfrac{\ln(y)^{1-k}}{1-k}+C$$

If $k=1$, $$\dfrac{1}{y\ln(y)}=\dfrac{1/y}{\ln(y)}$$

As the numerator is the derivative of the denominator, primitives will be of the form $\ln(|\ln(y)|)+C$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!